# Wordpress post enconding issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, encoding

I have a page originally encoded in iso-8859-1 which won't display correctly once incorporated into a wordpress post. I was able to replicate the issue outside of wordpress, forcing the encoding of the page to be read as utf-8 instead. Here you can see what happens:

ISO-8859-1 page: http://www.maxballet.it/sito/orari.php

UTF-8: http://www.maxballet.it/sito/orari2.php

Unfortunately i'm unable to show the original post itself, but that's exactly what happens.

So of course i understand that there's some issue at some step of the whole pipeline from the browser to the database i'm pulling the data from (probably some non-utf8 characters inside the database itself). But since investigating into this issue has been really time consuming for me during the past few days, after a few tries i instead tried to force the wordpress page encoding to be read as iso-8859-1 (via the `<meta>` tag), in order to quick-fix it while investigating.

Unfortunately, even tough firefox could be able to detect the wordpress post's page encoding as iso-8859-1, that didn't work, and the post still displays as the faulty example above.

I'm investigating the pipeline encoding issue myself and i posted about that here already into another question, but at this point i really need to let this page run again.

I'm probably missing something about the wordpress platform, which i am definetly not familiar with. So any suggestion on how to fix this inside wordpress without having to fix the whole pipeline would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

**UPDATE 1:** I forgot to mention that i've already tried to utf8_encode() any string coming from the database with no luck.

Comment: Seeing your other question, you're pulling this from a database. Try passing encoding to your DB connection right before your query. That sometimes fixes it. For example `mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');` or `$con->set_charset("utf8");`. There is also a PDO equivalent, but we don't know which API you're using.

Comment: Also make sure that the file(s) itself is saved as UTF-8.

Comment: That's what i've been suggested into the other question, and i was just going to try this right now. Thanks for your feedback, i'll post again once i've tried this

Comment: That fixed the issue. Everything's working flawless now. Thank you so much for that. If you wanna post that as the answer i'll mark yours as the solution

Comment: That's great (buonissimo) and you're welcome (prego), glad to hear it. It has been posted, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *That fixed the issue. Everything's working flawless now. Thank you so much for that. If you wanna post that as the answer i'll mark yours as the solution*

As per OP's wish to close the question as per my original comment:

Seeing your other question, you're pulling this from a database.

Try passing encoding to your DB connection right before your query.

That sometimes fixes it.

For example `mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');` or `$con->set_charset("utf8");`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) your content before echoing:

```
echo utf8_decode($content);//on iso-8859-1 page
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgot to mention i've already tried this, with no luck unfortunately.